# my program is not getting validated in jsonlint validater

Tags: php

```
 <?php$host="localhost";
$db="profile";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$connection=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if(!$connection){
        die("Database server connection failed.");
    }else{
 $dbconnect=mysql_select_db("profile",$connection);
if(!$dbconnect){
            die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
        }else{
$username=$_GET["username"];
$password=$_GET["password"];
$query="SELECT id,profile_id,username,password from home where username='$username'and password='$password'";
$resultset=mysql_query($query,
            $connection);
$records=array();
if($resultset===false){
                die(mysql_error());
            }
while($r=mysql_fetch_row($resultset)){
                $records[]=$r;
            }
echo json_encode($records);
        }
    }?>
```

and error is  `<?php$host="localhos^Expecting '{', '['`

please explain me where is the problem in my script. 
I m using `$_get[]` method to enter detail through url in my database but I m getting error. It works in localhost but not working in validator. I just want to run it in jsonlint. What I do I have to do to correct it ?

Comment: If this `<?php$host` is part of your actual code, start by splitting it up `<?php $host`. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: SQL injection found. You have bigger problems.

Comment: Plaintext passwords also found. MUCH bigger problems...

Comment: what kind of error did you get?

Comment: @bub Edit now in effect: `and error is <?php$host="localhos^Expecting '{', '['` - as per answered below, being the "editor".

Comment: I guess [this...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282061/my-program-is-not-getting-validated-in-jsonlint-validater#comment44918311_28282061) means squat. Incredible how injection-related comments get (more) UV's then the real issue at hand. It's like an infatuation, a drug if I can say.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry for that, was in the process of editing the answer, because of the blank after the _and the error is_ in the OP question when you posted your comment.

Comment: @b.enoit.be No need to be sorry Benoit, you did what you had to do ;-) it had nothing to do with you.

Comment: i tried that by giving space between but i still geting this Parse error on line 1:
<?php$host="localhos
^
Expecting '{', '['

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed missing a space between `<?php` and `$host` as the parser is saying it to you in your error.

Comment: sir i tried this but i am still gating this error Error: Parse error on line 1:
<?php $host="localho
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Comment: i m still gating this Parse error on line 1:
<?php$host="localhos
^
Expecting '{', '['

Answer (score 0):

please keep a space between

```
<?php$host="localhost"; sholud be corrected as `<?php $host="localhost";`
```